# Why am I getting smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (500, b'5.3.3 Unrecognized command') using code that worked a month ago?

Tags: python-3.x, exchangewebservices

I used the following code successfully last month to connect to and send mail through an Exchange server. I am using python 3.5.

```
import smtplib
# ...
s=smtplib.SMTP('outlook.office365.com', 587)
s.starttls()
s.login(user, pwd)
```

Today, it gives me

`smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (500, b'5.3.3 Unrecognized command')`

I see a related bug report [here](https://bugs.python.org/issue25446) but cannot figure out how that helps me.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You should call `ehlo()` after `starttls()`.

Comment: Does `ehlo()` need any arguments? Inserting `ehlo()` without arguments between `starttls()` and `login()` does not seem to change anything.

Comment: `ehlo` has  a default argument which is just fine - no need to supply anything. The library provides automatic `ehlo`, but it is not clearly stated, if it is the case also after `starttls`. Anyway, if it did not help, there must be another problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a bug introduced in python 3.5.0: https://bugs.python.org/issue25446, this should be fixed in python 3.5.1. (I haven't tried this yet, as I only stumbled upon this question while researching this bug)

Edit: just tested, smtplib + python 3.5.1 + office365 works

Answer (score 0):

Additional something else you may want to look at. Double check your username and password are typed out correctly. In python 3.5 the error shown would not explicitly tell you that your username is not correct you would only see

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (500, b'5.3.3 Unrecognized command')
```

for both incorrect credentials as well if using gmail less secure apps not allowed unlike python 3.6 where you would see

```
smtplib.SMTPAuthenticationError: (535, b'5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. Learn more at\n5.7.8  https
ials m11-v6sm24489408pfj.25 - gsmtp')
```

In the event your credentials are not correct.